# C++ avoid writing two similar functions

Tags: c++, templates

I want to have two version a function by hiding or not hiding several lines of code at the middle and also near the end of the function with template or other means. How to do that?

The functions are performance critical. They got run a gazillion of gazillion times.

Comment: **−1** As explained in a [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274811/c-avoid-writing-two-similar-functions#comment63969005_38274827), the examples and description are not examples and description of **the real problem**, which is something else. Also, the pseudo-code. Subtle differences like initialized in A, not in B.

Comment: Function B is declared as void but returns int

Comment: And `x` is not initialized.
Is `d` known in compile time?

Comment: why would you want to use a template? I would just do `if (flag) { /* line of code */}` and let the compiler and cpu do its job of optimizing and predicting

Comment: Here is a list of most downvoted questions: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36660/most-down-voted-questions Some of them are actually fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could implement the first one with a default parameter:

```
int A(int a, int b, int c, int d = 0)
{
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: @rxu Better try again with a realistic example? Something short that captures the essence of what you're trying to solve.

Comment: Move that default param to a compile-time param (i.e., template arg.) if you can. It helps the compiler a bit.

Comment: I think I will use tobi303's idea and the default argument. like `int A(int a, int b, int c, int flag);`  Then hide the extra lines with `if (flag){ /* things to hide */ }` Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 3):

You can factor out the common part and use a function object to pass the differing part:

```
template<class Fun>
int AB(Fun&& fun){
    int x = 0;
    Outer Loop{
        Inner Loop{
            x = std::forward<Fun>(fun)();
        }
    }
    return x;
}

int a, b, c, d;
// ... initialize
int result1 = AB([a,b,c]{
    return a + b;
});
int result2 = AB([a,b,c,d]{
    return a + b + c*d;
});
```

You could make this even more general by templating the return type.

There are no branches and an optimizing compiler will be able to expand the function call inline. The latter is the reason to prefer function objects to function pointers.

Comment: May be I can add `inline` to the `int result` function. Will that ensure the function get inline, even with the template?

Comment: @rxy there is no `int result` function. What do you mean? There is no way to ensure that a call will be expanded inline in standard c++. The best you can do is guarantee that a compiler **can** inline. A compiler can inline all calls shown in this example.

Comment: My bad. I mix this up with nosbor's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would suggest you to re-implement your code. But the one thing that is coming to my mind is using function as parameter, see below (you may also use lambda expression):

```
int fun1(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    return a + b;
}

int fun2(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    return a + b + c*d;
}

template <int (*FUN)(int, int, int, int)> int fun_main(int a, int b, int c, int d = 0) {
    int x = 0;
    Outer Loop{
        Inner Loop{
            x += FUN(a, b, c, d);
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Then somwhere in your code:

```
fun_main<fun1>(1, 2, 3, 4);
```